# Hibernate - save some Entity in one transaction

Tags: hibernate, entity, cascade

I have following scenario:

- Entity1
- Entity2
- Entity3
- Entity4

**Relationship:**

```
Entity1  1...n  Entity2 
Entity2  1...n  Entity3
Entity2  1...n  Entity4
```

Now I have one method which should save all these entities.
I use cascade for saving automatically Entity2, Entity3 and Entity4

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity2", cascade = { PERSIST, MERGE, REMOVE })
```

Currently I got following issue:

> Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance
>   must be saved before current operation

So is this scenario possible?
Or should I save first Entity1 with Entity2 ?

Answer (score 0):

probably u are not setting parentEntity in child setter,i.e.you need to set class A in class B, so when it save all hierarchy in single call ,it doesn't get parent entity in mapped By column,

```
Class A{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent" , Cascade = cascadeType.All)
    List<B> children;

 //children setter n getter

}

Class B{

@MAnyToOne
private A parent;

SetPArent(A a){    //like this you need to set for cascade saving.
  this.parent = a;
}
}
```

Now Hibernate will take care of setting parent parent(foreign Id) column in child table..and it all can be save in a single save call.